# Creating new array using Hash key and values in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have this question:

> Given the family of hash members, with keys as the title and an array
>   of names as the values, use the Ruby’s built in method to gather
>   immediate family members (“brothers” and “sisters”) only into a new
>   array.

With this hash:

```
family = {
  uncles:["bob", "joe", "steve"],
  sisters: ["jane", "jill", "beth"],
  brothers: ["frank", "rob", "david"],
  aunts: ["mary", "sally", "susan"]
}
```

How do I do this? I'm not even sure what built-in method I need to use. I'm a complete beginner in Ruby by the ways.

I have this:

```
new_family = Array.new
new_family = family.values_at(:brothers, :sisters)
p new_family
```

Which gives me:

```
[["frank", "rob", "david"], ["jane", "jill", "beth"]]
```

But I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly? I feel like I might not fully be understanding the question?

Comment: Just add `flatten` to the end (i.e. `new_family = family.values_at(:brothers, :sisters).flatten`. BTW you don't need `new_family = Array.new`.

Answer (score 3):

There are many different ways you could do this, you could simply do something like:

```
new_family = family[:brothers] + family[:sisters]
```

Or, like you have above:

```
new_family = family.values_at(:brothers, :sisters).flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one:

```
new_family = [:brothers, :sisters].flat_map(&family.method(:[]))
#=> ["frank", "rob", "david", "jane", "jill", "beth"]
```

Comment: `.flat_map(&family.method(:[]))` :)

Comment: @mudasobwa Nice! I like this better so I'll update my answer, thank you.